# Marking as duplicate can cause a very slow questions rate in the future

Tags: discussion

Many of the best questions about gaming were already asked. An answer posted now to them will not be significant. This means that new users will earn reputation harder. And in the future,because the question-asking rate is higher than the game-making rate,it will mean that questions will be asked much more slowly and the site will transform almost into an arhive. An action must be taken sometime to prevent this.

Comment: Yeah, but allowing dupes is definitely not the right approach.

Comment: There will always be new questions to ask because there will always be new games to ask questions about.

Answer (score 6):

Many of the best questions about gaming are still to be asked and answered also. As already said, there's many more games to come and there will be many more popular ones than the actual games.

You will not find many people that will find a alternative to the way duplicates are handled. There's [even discussions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/37466/227881) to give reputation to people marking questions as duplicates to help reduce the places where answers are found. Even if you ask a duplicated question, you might still gain some reputation for asking it in a different way but beware that asking a duplicate question without researching can also lead to a net lost of reputation.

Being present when a game is popular and ask or answer the questions about it during that time frame isn't something we can help with. Also, if all the games you're knowledgeable about are older ones, there's a good chance you'll not be able to gain reputation as easily as if you have good knowledge of the latest trending game.

With that said, what can be done to get more reputation? Not much more than writing good answers and questions. Even on already answered questions or asking a good question on a old game that hasn't been asked.

It might be slow but if you're doing it right, you'll gain reputation regardless of the age of the games you ask and answer questions for.

Remember that the motto is : [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tour) , having more than one place to find answers is a distraction.

Here's a few links that should give you more information on how to gain reputation as a new user and not to give up even if it's slow at the start :

- [A question that talks about gaining reputation as a new user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/178800/227881) on [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) but the basics apply to all Stack Exchange sites.
- [This one shouldn't contain much that you don't know, but its a good read](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/188611/227881)
- [Why keep on asking and answering, based on Stackoverflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/79624/227881) but the basics apply to all Stack Exchange sites.
- [Specific to Arqade, expectation for new users.](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/61395)
- and [another from here about new users experience.](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5040/61395)