# How to get an up to date answer for old questions with obsolete answers?

Tags: discussion, answers, exact-duplicates, old-questions, game-versions

Explanation whether duplicate or not --> see end of post.

Imagine you have a question about a game. You first search for it and find it answered a long time ago. Back then the answer was correct, but since then the game mechanics changed several times, so that it is now outdated and obviously wrong for the current version of the game.

How is it possible to get the very same question answered for the current version of the game?

In my case I just asked the same question again ([What is the rule of how many new quests you get at one day in Hearthstone 4.X?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/245108/what-is-the-rule-of-how-many-new-quests-you-get-at-one-day-in-hearthstone-4-x)). But the moderator said this does not comply with the policy ([Outdated Answers Due to Patches](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/946/outdated-answers-due-to-patches)), which in this case says, that I am supposed to update the answer of the old question.

But I have just the same question and not a new answer for that! Besides a bounty, I don't see another possibility to direct the attention of people to the old question again. And if I haven't enough reputation, I would not be able to put a bounty anyway. It cannot be the solution to wait for a new answer to the old question, can it? So if somebody was new here, it seems to be impossible for her/him to get an up to date answer to the old question. Is that right?

If yes, wouldn't it be reasonable to change something? Maybe it should be possible to mark outdated answers and move questions to the top again. Of course after some approval. Just an idea...

There is a very similar question ([How should we deal with out of date questions/answers?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1339/how-should-we-deal-with-out-of-date-questions-answers)) as suggested in the comments, but the answer is not applicable to my case. The accepted answer in this thread just suggests to edit the question and write new or edit existing answers. **But I have exactly the same question, but no answer for it**. So I cannot take the actions suggested in this thread.

**EDIT 1**

**Here I would like to explain why this post might be a duplicate, but is necessary anyway** *(Please excuse my poor English, I am not a native speaker)*

This question might be a duplicate, yes, but this is what the topic of the post is about. There is currently no way to get answers to a very same question which was asked before, but the answers became wrong and outdated in the meantime, due to game patches etc. The policy suggests [here](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/946/outdated-answers-due-to-patches) and [here](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1339/how-should-we-deal-with-out-of-date-questions-answers) (same links as above) that the old answers and/or questions are supposed to be edited. To edit the question doesn't make sence, because I have the very same question. And in my opinion there is no point of editing the answers either, because on the one hand I don't know the answer, because I am searching for it, and on the other hand who will notice if I put a warning that the answer is wrong?

Who might notice:

- The original authors, who might not know the answer.
- Users searching for the answer to the question, who don't know it, either.

I think there is a lack of the possibility to direct all users attention to an old question which needs a new answer. It must be the attention of all users, because it is much more likely that one of them knows the answer compared to just the few people which were involved in the thread back then. Of course an expensive bounty is one solution, but not everybody can afford a bounty. Besides the bounty, the only possibility is to ask the very same question again, which is not allowed by the policy. We need something else!

Ironically, the very same thing is currently happening to this meta post, since there were already answers to quite similar questions. But the answers of those cannot be applied to the case I described. That is, why I think it is important to discuss it again and why I think, the existing threads are not enough (because almost nobody cares about / notices old threads = the problem what this post is about).

Comment: The moderator? You don't mean me, do you?

Comment: @Studoku Yes, I do! Are you not? I'm sorry...

Comment: Apology accepted. In future, you can recognise mods by the diamond ♦ next to their username.

Comment: I think the duplicate I raised is applicable still because essentially the recommendation is to either edit the out of date info with a disclaimer and/or add comments so that others (e.g. original author) can make corrections.  Such actions will also bring questions "to the top" so to speak, so others will also become aware of the changes.

Comment: Also, I have seen others with high rep place bounties on such questions in the past.

Comment: @CamelCase That is the problem: If I edit an answer in the old thread nobody except maybe the author of the answer and others who are searching for an answer to the question will notice. Neither does the original author nor I know the answer to the question for the current version of the game. So it remains unanswered and outdated and nobody is allowed to ask the question again or to do anything else about it. The ironical thing is, that the same problem now happens to this meta post. It kind of is a duplicate, yes, but in my opinion there is still no good solution.

Comment: @Rob - There's no easy solution to this issue.  I've thrown a bounty on the old question, as that really is the best we can do.

Comment: @JasonBerkan Thanks, but somehow the question about the game became a minor matter. Good mechanics became more important, now. ;-)

Comment: @Rob - where are we with the original question?  It looks like changes have been made to reflect the current state of the game (although this looks like it will change again in the next patch if I am reading it right!).

Comment: @CamelCase Sorean posted a very satisfactory answer in the original thread. But yes, it will change again, and then we will have 2 outdated, high rated answers in the thread. By the way, I don't know what to do with this meta thread? Am I supposed to accept an answer? They have 0, 0 and -1 votes... I think it's not reasonable for one to be chosen, especially not by me.

Comment: @Rob - High rated because people found them useful/worthy.  I wouldn't associate highest answer or accepted answer as the correct answer as a rule of thumb, more a guideline.  Otherwise we would only have questions with 1 answer.  The post has had a lot of publicity in the past week so the increase of votes is expected (plus it has a bounty).  As for accepting a meta answer, you don't have to accept any.  Is there an eta on the bug fix?  May be best to wait until then.

Comment: @Rob - also, you may only be able to see the net affect of voting on answers.  There have been 42 votes (at this point) across all 3 answers.  Pretty even split of agree/disagree for each answer.

Comment: @CamelCase You mean the comment votes? Or where can I see the number of votes an answer received? After I read all the answers, comments and linked threads, I think I understand both views on the subject. I will do it later when I have more time...

Comment: @Rob - when you get a high enough rep you can click on the answer votes.  It gives you a break down on the up and down votes.

Comment: @Rob - In particular, it takes 1000 rep to see the vote breakdown.  http://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/established-user  
Unfortunately, as shown by the rep league chart at http://stackexchange.com/leagues/7/year/gaming/2015-01-01?sort=reputationchange, it takes most people over a year to gain that much.

Comment: There are many questions that are good questions in their current state even if the game got changed a lot. It's sometimes just that their answers explains stuff with certain items that aren't even in the game anymore. I'd love to update all those answers but I would need 2k Rep before I can do that without having to worry about other people taking a look at my edits first.

Answer (score 4):

I think it's pretty clear from the comment votes that the only thing we all agree on is there is a problem here.

In a perfect world, a new question is asked, marked as a dupe, asker either a) comments on the original answer to say it's out of date or b) complains on their dupe loudly enough that someone does it for them (if their rep is too low, for example). The author of that answer gets a notification and updates the answer. We close the dupe, everybody wins.

Equally perfectly, the author of the original question notices the comments on the answer, and removes the checkmark. When a correct answer is posted, they accept the new answer.

I don't think I'm risking too much by saying we can all agree the best case is either of those two (or something very close to them).

That's not always going to be the case, and we need a policy for when this stops working. Let's briefly go over the rationale for my proposal.

I don't like editing the accepted answer because the votes go to the wrong place. If the editor is wrong, they have nothing to lose. Clearly if the answer is abandoned, the author doesn't care what happens to their rep, so why should a third party edit net them more or dock them? And if we edit in a disclaimer, why let the incorrect information stand? That doesn't seem to be in line with the spirit of our edit policies, at least not to me.

Bounties are great, but it puts too much onus on to few users. I just hit 3K, I'm not placing any bounties that will lose my voting privileges. It seems to be a trend that folks with extremely high rep forget how much of what you can do is based on relatively high rep scores. 200 rep is a lot when you have 3K.

Finally, down-voting simply doesn't work, if the answer has been abandoned, that original author doesn't care. All the reasons bounties are subpar apply here as well.

**If it becomes clear to reasonable members of the community that the accepted answer to an abandoned question is both out of date and abandoned by it's author, we should delete the answer.** What flag to raise could be debated, but I say we use "moderator attention." We normally shy away from one user making categorical statements about accuracy, but that's because we rely on the voting system to make sure the good stuff rises to the top. The system falls apart on mature questions, for a two simple reasons. First, a question with an accepted answers will draw less view from the community, which gives less chance for those down-votes or a new, accurate answer. Secondly, rather than starting at zero like normal, the answer "starts" with up-votes.

We have a responsibility to prune old information from the site, especially when that old information is inaccurate. We've yet to have an actionable policy about this, and we truly need one with the games of today. So please, if this proposal is unacceptable to you, let's work on hammering one together. Our band-aid fixes won't keep working forever.

(I'm aware the question that spawned this has been taken care of, and if you think this meta had absolutely nothing to do with that, well, I admire your faith in humanity. Me, I think it played a major role, so pointing to the question in question as an example of the system working doesn't hold much water with me.)

EDIT: I should really have slept on this before posting. I thought what I was saying was obvious, but it l clearly isn't.

I'm not proposing we immediately delete a question as soon as it's outdated. We'd first behave normally, commenting on the question and answer to give everyone a chance to correct it normally. If neither the author of the question nor the answer makes any change within some agreed upon grace period (7 days? 10? 14? I don't know, please suggest something, I'm here everyday, my perspective of reasonable  is probably skewed), then and only then do we take steps to delete the accepted answer.

Comment: How do we determine a question is abandoned?  How about if the answer is out of date?  Why should mods be tasked with deleting this?  They're not going to be experts in every single game.  Does that mean we close outdated questions so that 10K+ can vote to delete?  That runs headlong into another meta, where we leave old questions alone.  At the end of the day, all you're doing here is creating more problems.

Comment: There's no reason to have spoiler markup in a meta answer. I've removed it.

Comment: Nice point on obsolete answers starting with upvotes, especially if they were very well received.  Also not to forget is that questions can't be voted on again unless edited after a period of time, so a +21 question would have to be first edited before any of those voters could even change their vote. I see deletion as a better option, although I don't like the idea of taking away the answerer's rep just because the answer is outdated.

Comment: Wait your stance is to delete all out of date questions and answers? How is that fair, people will lose thousands of rep.

Comment: Sorry, I just re-read your proposal; I had originally thought you were proposing deletion of questions and answers.  If it's just about deleting out of date answers, I would support that, but only for games where there is effectively only one version playable.  So for MMO's, and other online only games, generally.

Comment: @Aequitas 1st, I said nothing about questions. 2nd, rep is permanent after 60 days. 3rd, even if the rep WAS lost, if someone can't be bothered to edit their own question after its brought up that it's wrong, they don't care about their rep.

Comment: @Frank these days, it's most games. You have to actively try to keep a game out of date on PC, and if your (modern) console is connected to the Internet, you CANT play previous versions. I guess I don't see the benefit of keeping an answer out of date for a tiny fraction of users who both play the game on that exact version and just so happen to have the same question. Minecraft is really the only example I can think of off hand that has a decent chuck of users who play old patches. That doesn't mean they don't exist, though.

Comment: While it isn't desirable to have inaccurate answers hanging around with positive scores and checkmarks, it's not the mods' job to determine the accuracy of an answer. In fact, there's a specific flag rejection reason that indicates that flags should not be used to point out technical inaccuracies in an answer.

Comment: @Frank as to how we determine whether a question is abandoned, the first step would be to check the original authors profile. If they are still active, they should be given more or less unlimited time to make whatever edits are necessary. If they haven't logged in for years... I don't have any concept of a fair grace period, I've been here everyday since I joined (I'm assuming that's not typical). I would think a week would be too little time. It not like I think we should burn questions the instant a patch drops as a first step.

Comment: @Unionhawk because we rely on the voting system to determine accuracy. I mentioned that in the answer. Am I wrong in thinking there's no extant method for a user to mark an answer for deletion?

Comment: @Dallium The only people who can delete answers with 0 score or greater are moderators, and their actions are binding. So your only option would potentially be to raise a moderator attention flag that the answer is incorrect. Now it is the job of one moderator to determine if the answer is actually incorrect. Ultimately, moderators aren't here to do that, regardless of the age of an answer.

Comment: @Unionhawk right now they aren't, yeah, because the current practice is to just shrug and let out of date info stand. I don't think we'd have much success with a feature request asking for a mark for deletion flag for answers, but it might be worth a shot. The subject matter in other stacks isn't as changeable as it is here. The bald fact is this is going to happen more and more as games continue to be released bigger and buggier and get major patches well into their lifetimes, even single player games. We need to be able to do SOMETHING.

Comment: At the moment, I can't support this proposal.  Answers are useful forever, unless they're for an online game.  I'd support a mod delete for outdated answers, with those caveats, but we'd definitely have to put bounds and process on it.

Comment: This sounds pretty good for the most part, but the issue of placing the burden for deciding whether it's out of date on the moderators is pretty significant. Maybe if we had a review queue for out of date answers?

Comment: @Frank Nowadays, what games aren't online? Even single-player games like Skyrim get major patches years after their release that fix many problems that may have solutions posted here. Should we really keep posts around with what is essentially now misinformation? What if there is a similar-but-not-same issue that someone tries to apply the accepted fix for? I think this is an issue that deserves attention sooner rather than later. Even if it isn't a serious problem now, it almost certainly will be in the future.

Comment: @nukeforum The thing is, some people don't have the latest version.  That's *fine*.  We can gather more answers for the most up to date version, and that's great.  We should be deleting old answers because it's not the latest and greatest?  That seems counter-productive; the old version can still be played, so the answers are still useful.

Comment: @Frank Which people? Updates are automatic in the majority of cases.

Comment: @nukeforum For online games.  Not so for single player ones. What if they don't have reliable or regular internet?  We should be punishing players of old versions?

Comment: @Frank I'm having a hard time seeing how someone could have reliable/regular enough internet to do research on fixing their problem, but not reliable enough to get a patch.

Comment: @nukeforum Rather easily.  A library can be commonly used.  Either way, though, the fact is that old versions are still playable, in most cases.  Getting rid of those answers does us a disservice.

Comment: @Frank Ok, I concede the point. I had never heard of library computers being used for playing Skyrim.

Comment: @nukeforum Well, I had more meant to use libraries to research their issues, not play Skyrim.  Just to clarify, as that wasn't what I had meant. :)

Comment: @Frank "For online games. Not so for single player ones." This is essentially false and you must know it. A tiny, infinitesimal fraction of a percentage of players play old patches. The idea of leaving stale and inaccurate information as the top answer for such a vanishing minority is ludicrous.

Comment: How is that ludicrous?  People *play* those old games!  That's what we're here for!  Not just the latest and greatest, but the old ones.  Answers are write once, read **many**.  You yourself might not, but others *will*.  That's the nature of the beast.  Catering to only those who keep their game up to date does us, and them, a massive disservice.

Comment: @Frank no, keeping old information to mislead the vast majority in order to cater to the literally ones of users who find the information useful is the massive disservice. To us and to that massive majority. To us, answers are read many, we know how the site works. That is not a safe assumption to apply broadly. It'd be like if someone asks "Is it safe to go outside without a space suit," and there was an answer from 4 billion years ago saying no we were trying to update, but someone says "AH! but there are 3 people in the ISS who would die if they followed that advice, so the answer stands!"

Comment: That's a strawman, and you know it.  There's always a chance someone will be playing an older version.  The reasoning why is immaterial.  Deleting answers that would help that person (or persons, whatever) is wasteful.  Why not just let it stay?  Prepend it with the version it's applicable to, and let it be.  If users get confused because the answer isn't applicable to their version, then they need to read better.

Comment: Either way, though, adding additional curation efforts isn't really feasible.  The only ones who can delete upvoted answers are mods, and we're not going to be putting this all on their shoulders; they have enough to do.  You're not going to get enough downvotes for old answers for even 20k'ers to help.  I know; I've tried.

Comment: @Frank we shouldn't let it stay because it ACTIVELY HARMFUL to the greater majority. If there's no accepted answer, fine, whatever, we can up-vote/down-vote until the correct answer for the version that 99.999999999999999% of users play is on top. Curating this site SHOULD be hard. It's supposed to be harder on us than it is on new users or passersby. EVERYTHING we do should be in done with the goal of making every aspect of the site more accessible and more readable. I'm not suggesting we reduce our ability to curate at all. But there's not some secret metric of new user experience vs (cont)

Comment: They are NOT actively harmful.  How is an answer for an old version *actively harmful*!?  It does **nothing** to keep it.

Comment: ability to curate. And for the millionth time, I'm NOT placing the burden on the mods, they are merely executing the action. If they get a moderator attention flag, and the only thing is a note on the flag saying, "this answer is out of date delete plz," with no comments on the question or answer itself, they should reject it. However, if they get one and there is a string of comments saying "This answer is out of date as of patch whatever" and repeated support for it's removal, they aren't actually making a decision at that point, they're going along with the community.

Comment: That's still additional moderation overhead.  Mods are **exception** handlers.  Not rote button pushers.  Outdated answers aren't an exception.  They're a fact of life.  They won't be able to do anything **but** delete outdated answers.  They have much more important duties to perform than sweep answers that can still be useful to other readers.

Comment: @Frank they absolutely, unequivocally, unavoidably harmful if they're the top answer. That's the first and last place a driveby user will look. They just got bad information. That's bad. Bad information is bad.

Comment: No, they're *not*. If a reader only reads the top answer, and it's not helpful to them, then chances are pretty good they didn't read the whole thing.  I can absolutely support deleting outdated accepted answers for games that have only a single version, but acceptance is somewhat of an inviolate action that we don't interfere with.  The best we can (and should, for multi-version games), is pre-pend it for the applicable version, so readers are aware the accepted answer isn't for the latest version.  Beyond that, votes will sort the answers properly.

Answer (score 3):

**Our duplicate policy shouldn't apply to outdated questions**

Stack Exchange works around votes and accepted answers, allowing good answers to rise to the top. This does not work as intended if answers earn votes then become incorrect.

In many cases, the asker of the old question is no longer an active user. This means that even if the updated answer is posted, and it gets enough attention and votes to rise above any other answers, it will always be below the accepted, incorrect answer.

Editing the correct answer into the accepted answer, which is often suggested, goes against our edit policies and means we allow users to attribute answers to other users. It also sets a dangerous precedent- if we edit outdated answers, what about incorrect answers?

Instead, users should be able to re-ask outdated questions and get the answers they need- that's what we're for, right? The old question should be closed or edited and linked to the new one if it gets a good answer.

Comment: What?  No!  How do we determine if an answer is outdated?  It's a bit more effort for us to try to keep old questions up to date, but that's why we rely on established users to do what is needful; it's still a dupe, so one of us can bounty the original.  Done and done.

Comment: @Frank Does a bounty-reward answer appear above an accepted answer?

Comment: Nothing appears above an accepted answer.  There's nothing preventing an asker from accepting an altogether wrong answer, either, so it's not really relevant to the problem.

Comment: @Frank Aside from the fact that that almost never happens, whereas answers becoming outdated are getting more and more common.

Comment: Entropy kind of dictates that; it happens on SO quite often.  If answers are outdated, fix it!  Don't gunk up the process by allowing dupe to exist.

Comment: How are you supposed to fix outdated answers, if you don't know the answer? That is the problem! The attention of others who might know, must be directed somehow. Duplicates could be part of the process, if the outdated threads are deleted / closed / linked / merged. Everything would stay tidied up, if something happens to the old thread. The appropriate (not yet existing) feature or a changed policy is the question in my opinion.

Comment: @Frank the gunk is the outdated questions and answers, not the new relevant ones. The outdated content serves no useful purpose and may actively confuse users.

Comment: @Dallium No, the gunk is multiple questions all asking the same thing.  Outdated answers can still serve a purpose, if those versions can still be played.  If it's an online thing, and you can't play anything but the latest version, *downvote them*!  That's what it's for!

Comment: The whole point of duplicates is to gather all the information into a single spot. We're trying to get *away* from the forum format, where people have to dig through multiple threads to find their answers.

Comment: @Frank for the question to be outdated, by definition, the version can't be playable (or at least, not playable in an official capacity). Honestly, from what (little) I know about how questions age, it seems clear that the system was designed from the ground up to deleted outdated questions. Don't they not lose rep after a certain amount of time has past if the question is deleted? And no, downvoting an answer that is incorrect NOW, but was correct back then is NOT what downvoting is for. Why would you want to hang onto questions that are terrible because they're old?

Comment: We have a responsibility to prune old information, and pointing new users at questions that are multiple patches out of date doesn't serve our mission at all.

Comment: @Frank So now we're punishing people who answer questions that happen to become outdated.?

Comment: No, we're judging content *that is no longer useful*. We don't judge users here, @Studoku. You know that. Besides, by that point, they've already gained a ton more rep from the answer than they're losing. If an answer is no longer useful, *that's what downvotes are for*. That's literally in their description!

Comment: We downvote non useful answers. If your answer is wrong, but it was right back then, it is still not helpful, now. If the author of the answer is still around, and is concerned about losing their rep, they should equally be ensuring the answer is up to date. If you post a comment to explain your downvoting due to the information being invalidated, the author will be alerted. I will personally convert my answers to wikis if they concern online games I do not play, anymore.

Comment: See, this is my issue with the whole thing. Lets pretend I upvoted the original answers, because it's right. Here comes newb McGee because the answer is out of date. Unless I make a trivial edit to the answer (which is dead wrong now) I CAN'T convert my upvote to a downvote. But I don't know the new answer, and neither do the other 17 people who upvoted the original answer. Lets just close the old one, because active users of said game are saying it isn't useful anymore.

Comment: I feel like @Frank 's solution is great, in a world where no one ever leaves a website and is always dedicated to it's goals. But here in the real world, the original asker either isn't a memeber here anymore, or doesn't play the game anymore, or both, and so gives exactly zero fucks as to the accuracy of the answer to their question. So that totally inaccurate accepted answer stays at the top, regardless of disclaimers. And it's up to US, the community members who DO GAF, to make sure ACCURATE information rises to the top. Close old, upvote new.

Comment: @Dallium And for those that *do* care, we expect more because of that.  Throw a bounty on the original question!  Answers needing updating is *literally* one of those bounty reasons!  If an accepted answer is wrong, and the owner doesn't seem to care, I would support a mod deletion.  Then the community can vote as needed, and accuracy is preserved just fine.

Comment: Just having a second question with the new information isn't also going to stop people from ending up at the old question through google, and only finding wrong information. If you add the correct answers to that question they *also* find the correct information.

Comment: @Arperum what second question? We deleted the old one. It wasn't relevant so we deleted it.

Comment: @Dallium Wait, what?  We're deleting the old questions now?  Who's proposing that?  I'm not seeing any proposal for that.

Comment: @Dallium, in terms of your issue regarding unable to undo upvote, I was under the impression that we were permitted to add "this answer is invalidated as of patch x.y" at the top of answers that were outright incorrect due to updates

Comment: @Timelord64 As I said in my answer, that disclaimer makes no sense to me. As far as editing goes, we should either let the information stand, or remove it completely. The disclaimer makes it seem like we don't know what we're doing.

Comment: @Dallium but the answer isn't wrong, it just only applies to a set of versions.

Comment: @Aequitas which basically no one plays anymore. And if it's a MMO or MOBA or large swath of console games, no one CAN play anymore. The version effectively  no longer exists, for all intents and purposes. It is therefore objectively wrong

Comment: @Dallium It's wrong for the current version, that doesn't mean it should be removed from history. It's historically correct. Like how the earth was flat

Comment: @Aequitas and if the original author edits them or if the question author revokes the check mark, they don't have to be. Our mission is not historical preservation, it's to provide answers to questions. If that answer is wrong, we have a duty to ensure it gets corrected or removed.

Comment: @Dallium, I agree, but we also do not remove answers on the basis of being incorrect. Instead, we downvote them. With the disclaimer edited in, you can reverse any upvote you provided to an out of date answer, and if OP corrects it with another edit, you can upvote it again.

Comment: @Timelord64 so user x answers a question, next month there's a major patch which invalidates their answer, is it fair and right that everyone swaps their upvotes on the answer to downvotes, making x lose all the reputation they gained and then some? X has put in time and effort to make a good answer and then loses rep for it?

Comment: @Timelord64 we don't remove them, right. We absolutely should. I cannot support the disclaimer edit. It makes zero sense to me. It's vandalism, plain and simple, and if we're going to do that, we might as well be honest about it and just nuke it.

Comment: The not nuking an answer is more the spirit of SE. Once in the negative, the answer even comes up on the low quality feed, I believe. If a user is not ensuring their answer is up to date, they should expect downvotes. If their answer is ultimately unhelpful for new users, it will be downvoted. thats how downvoting works

Comment: @Timelord64 that's ridiculous, posting an answer doesn't mean you're committing to update that answer forever (or for the 60 days or wateva it is until your rep is locked in). If there's a change the day after an answer is posted and other people see the answer and downvote it simply because it's out of date is downright stupid. You'll be punishing people who have actually put effort into an answer for something outside of their control. You'll be deterring people from becoming a part of the arqade community.

Comment: @Aequitas, I do agree with you in how it SHOULD work, but thats not how it WILL work. If users read an answer that is not helpful, there is a chance they will downvote. Im doubtful there will be much consideration, in this process, to if the answer was right at some point in time. Perhaps we could petition for a feature to allow the rep to be 'locked', so the user is not punished for downvotes. I think we have an issue here that is far more unique to gaming then many other SE sites' topics.

Comment: @Aequitas If someone posts an answer, the game gets updated the next day, and their answer doesn't, they *should* get downvotes.  The point is that answers are supposed to be write once, read *many*.  An obsolete answer is not useful, and that's **exactly** what downvotes are for.

Comment: @Frank at the time that they wrote it, it was useful for the future, it's not that person's fault that the game got updated. It may not even be their fault that they didn't update their answer, they may have been busy. Why would we punish someone for writing a good answer that became outdated due to a change in the game? I do not think downvoting the answer to the point that the OP deletes it is the way to handle these situations.

Comment: @Aequitas If the answer is no longer useful, it should be downvoted.  That's the whole *point* of downvotes.  If the answerer doesn't want that to happen, they can delete or update their answer as desired.  It's not about the user; never has been.  It's all about the content.  And it's no longer useful, so it should be downvoted.  Note that this is specifically for online games, where there is effectively only one version.  If it's playable offline, it's fine to leave it as is, to my view.

Answer (score -4):

I believe this meta is a duplicate of the following:

[How should we deal with out of date questions/answers?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1339/how-should-we-deal-with-out-of-date-questions-answers)

The concerns and answers provided cover the concerns highlighted by the OP of this meta.

> If the question is still relevant, but in some way no longer accurate, it should be edited to reflect the current reality. Answers can then be edited, or a new answer written as needed.

This will allow for amendments, where appropriate, to be made to the question.  More importantly, it allows for incorrect answers (due to a patch) to be given a disclaimer.

> If the question is abandoned, and the accepted answer is inaccurate and it is unlikely for the accept to be moved, editing it to add a disclaimer notifying readers about that fact and pointing them to a newer answer is considered the Right Thing To Do.

As above, but addresses concerns where the accepted answer does not change.

The OP is concerned moreso (in my opinion) with the possibility that no one will answer the question without a new question being added.  However, any edits will bring the question to the top of the active questions list.  Edits will notify the original asker, and to people who answered the original question.  They may also be the ones with the expertise to provide an updated answer.

A bounty can be used to promote a question, and an option exists to request for updated answer.

I think this still holds true:

> I personally see no problem with this method, and don't see any reason that we need any sort of special mechanics to revoke acceptance or any such beyond the tools we already have.

Comment: The current mechanics is, to edit the question? Although,I want to know the answer to the very same question? Editing will bring it to the top. So to discuss again,I would have to rewrite the question of the thread you are citing? Does this "bringing to the top" also apply when editing an accepted but outdated answer? This is what actually needs editing. Otherwise someone has to edit the question again,after a correct answer was given. And if somebody cannot edit answers and gives a new and correct answer,who accepts the answer if the asker is not active anymore? That is still an open problem.

Comment: Are you sure people will notice an edited answered question?  99% of the time it's at the top of the list because some spammer or NAA post bumped it.  I don't think people are genuinely looking for subtle signs that answers are out of date.

Comment: "Oh look, an answered question is at the top of the site. Ignore"

Comment: If you don't have enough reputation to use a bounty, then for sure your edit will go into a review queue.  This gets the attention of at least 2 high rep members.  Also, as I said previously, it gets the attention of people involved in the original question.  Plus people may be watching the game's tag, and of course people watching old questions rise to the top of the active list.  Surely, most of these actions will help get an updated answer for the question?  It did for the question that was the source of this meta.

Answer (score -4):

If we're not closing new questions as duplicates because our existing answers are outdated, we're failing one of our core tenants: To cut the noise to signal ratio.  By allowing them to exist, we will start versioning questions;  how does this mechanic work in version 1?  Version 2?  Version 3?  Are we *really* making the internet a better place by deliberately allowing duplicates because the current answers are outdated?  Should we be duping the old ones to the new ones?  We'll eventually end up with long dupe chains, and that's even worse for user experience and SEO.  Now they have to follow a long chain to actually get their answer.  Do we not dupe them at all?  Now users have to troll through several versions of the same question, trying to find the correct one that applies to them.  That's one of the exact things SE was created to *counter*, not encourage.

I subscribe to the late [@MarkTrapp's answer](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5242/20456): We expect more from established users, so that new users can get answers to their duplicate questions.  If it's a dupe, dupe it.  **Then bounty the original**.  We're here to help curate the site; it's not the best solution, but it's much better than allowing duplicates to exist.  It keeps all the answers in a single place, whether or not you can play the old versions.

If it's an online game, and an answer is no longer relevant because it's for an older version, *use your downvotes*.  That's what they're for, after all; denoting that an answer is no longer useful.  That will hopefully spur the answerer to update or delete their answer, and then everybody wins.  In extreme cases, if an outdated answer is accepted, and an update or delete isn't happening, we can flag for mod removal.  If not, the downvotes will indicate that an answer is no longer useful, and make it less likely for users to read it.

That's using the tools at our disposal to their maximum effect.  We don't need to allow duplicates.  We just need to expect more of ourselves.

Comment: Are we really making the internet a better place by deliberately allowing duplicates because the current answers are outdated? Yes. Unequivocally, absolutely, yes.

Comment: @Dallium No.  No, we're not.  We're creating additional cruft, which is one of the very things SE was created to *prevent*.  Having to search through multiple threads to try to find an answer is why SE is so focused on questions and answers.  We're killing that process by allowing duplicates.

Comment: You're essentially putting the new user experience above that of site curation.  At the end of the day, we're here to help *many* users.  Not just the one that asked the question.

Comment: @Dallium as I also said on the other answer: your duplicate question can and *will* confuse people. People will find the old question that doesn't contain any correct information anymore, but not find the new and correct information. By updating the old question with new answers they do find the new and correct information.

Comment: Essentially what you are proposing is to let old, outdated, inaccurate answers stand because you can't be bothered to curate the site.

Comment: @Dallium, I think it is better to assume the user can scroll down and check the next answer, if the previous does not work, then to go against one of the basic tenants of stack exchange. We dont do duplicates. Period. That is why "duplicate" is its own close reason.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that if nobody wants to bounty the question to get it updated, we have a question with an incorrect answer that will appear to others as correct.  There should be another solution.

Comment: @MikeR You're welcome to come up with one. So far, this seems to be the best we have. Allowing duplicates is a non-starter. If no one is willing to bounty the original, then Arqade is no longer fulfilling its function, and we might as well shut the site down

Comment: The duplicate question is only a symptom.  The root problem is that there is an accepted answer which was previously correct but no longer is.  What do we do in those cases?  Do that here as well.  ( I couldn't tell what the policy regarding regarding out-of-date answers is.  There are multiple meta questions on that topic and the accepted answers for those don't seem to agree with each other or with the policy that edits should not change the intent of the answer.)

Comment: I'm not sure we have a set policy, but I believe a case could be made for flagging for deletion. Only for games where there's effectively one version,though; MMO's and the like. For offline games, we'll just need to keep accruing different versions answers; they're all useful.

Comment: @Frank I agree with the flag for deletion idea, and that a distinction needs to be made between online games with forced updates and other games.